# Have problem: Value of type 'Result<Any, AFError>' has no member 'value'

Tags: json, swift, alamofire

trying to get value from result. Anybody knows how to fix it? Maybe some another solution of else.

```
func downloadForecastWeather(completed: @escaping DownloadComplete) {
    Alamofire.request(FORECAST_API_URL).responseJSON { (response) in
        let result = response.result
        if let dictionary = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> { // There is an error.
            if let list = dictionary["list"] as? [Dictionary<String, AnyObject>] {
                for item in list {
                    let forecast = ForecastWeather(weatherDict: item)
                    self.forecastArray.append(forecast)
                }
                self.forecastArray.remove(at: 0)
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        completed()
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use value, then call `value` on `response`
For example : `response.value`

So this will be

```
if let dictionary = result.value as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
```

If you want to use `result` then it should be like this

```html
let result = response.result
switch result {
 case .success(let data):
  //Parse data
 case .failure(let afError):
  //Handle error
}
```

Please refer to the below screenshot of `Response` from Alamofire for reference :

[image]